# How to manage transactions in Apache Spark?

Tags: transactions, rollback, apache-spark-sql

I want to use spark sql for data persistent, Can I rollback transaction in spark if transaction failed in between?

E.g. Lets say we have 3 tables t1, t2 and t3. t1 and t2 table data is persisted successfully but some how t3 failed in data integrity level. Can I roll back t1 and t2 data which is persisted in DB?

> Is there any spark way to roll back the transaction?